# How can I pick up name of file in archive and save it as variable?

Tags: ansible

I hope I can explain this clearly, as I encounter one problem and need to use something apart from simply mv (rename) module in Ansible.

I have a task and one of the problem I encounter is that I need to download one file, which has name `file-latest.zip`. When I unarchive it, first folder I see will be name `file-1.2.20` for example. Now, of that name depends how I am going to organize many files and templates. Next time, behind this `file-latest.zip` will be updated version or `file-1.2.21`, which I never know.

I would like somehow, when I unarchive, to save it in some variables latest name of that file and then to work further with that variable, but I am not too sure how to figure this out.

I am very beginner in this and this gave me so many thoughts and could not go around and find solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way, if you do have the folder as an unique direct child of your archive would be to use the parameter [`list_files: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-list_files), and gather the directory.

Given a file *file-latest.zip*:

```bash
$ unzip -l file-latest.zip 
Archive:  file-latest.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  06-13-2022 15:19   file-1.2.21/
        0  06-13-2022 11:01   file-1.2.21/foo
        0  06-13-2022 15:19   file-1.2.21/baz
        0  06-13-2022 15:19   file-1.2.21/bar
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files
```

The two tasks:

```yaml
- unarchive:
    src: file-latest.zip
    list_files: true
    dest: /tmp
  register: zip_content

- debug:
    var: zip_content.files[0][:-1]
```

Would unarchive the zip on the target node and yield:

```yaml
TASK [unarchive] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  zip_content.files[0][:-1]: file-1.2.21
```

From there, you can use it as is or register it in a variable using the `set_fact` module, e.g.:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    archive_version_name: "{{ zip_content.files[0][:-1] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works really good this way as well. If i understand correctly with set_fact i will save variable in local task. My problem is that i would need somehow to connect this with group_vars, to be recognized in other roles also, is there any way i could manage it? One more time thanks for your effort and kind clearance!

Comment: @Stigla7 nope, facts are registered on the nodes, per default, not on the controller. Also, for the record, I updated this answer, as I realised adding `list_files: true` just adds an information to the `unarchive` task but still does the actual unarchiving, so there is no need to run that twice.